# R, Metafor package and Latex output

Tags: tables, r

I have a problem in exporting output produced in R using the metafor package to latex. The object I'm trying to export are few rma and rma.mv outputs. As example, I'll post some output of the rma function:

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 96; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0176 (SE = 0.0027)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.1328
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   99.72%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  356.39

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 95) = 3539.7360, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
-0.0456   0.0140  -3.2680   0.0011  -0.0729  -0.0182       ** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I tried to export this objects as tables with texreg and stargazer but they don't have rma functions implemented. Is there another way to avoid producing the tables manually (it might get messy when I'll have to include multiple output per table)? Or should I use another approach?

Cheers,

Marco

Comment: Do you use [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/)?

Comment: No I don't, it's actually one of my first analysis in R and so far I only dealt with basic\common packages who could be easily formatted in latex. Should I look over knitr?